# in libgdx how do you print a count down timer?

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx, countdown

i want my game to run for ten seconds print the seconds and when it hits 0 the game is over. As of right now i can print from 0 to 10 and it makes it game over at 10 seconds but i need the reverse.

```
   time+= delta;
    System.out.println(String.format("time: %,.2f", time));

    if(!tOn) {
             tOn = true;

             Timer.schedule(new Task() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;

                }

             }, 10);
        }
```

Comment: So make time start at ten and `-= delta;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set your variable `time = 10` and decrement it as `time--` inside your `Timer` and print the same.

```
    int time = 10;

    System.out.println(String.format("time: %,.2f", time));

    if(!tOn) {
             tOn = true;
             Timer.schedule(new Task() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     time--;
                     if(time == 0){
                       currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;
                     }
                }
             }, 10);
        }
```